# Angular - Overwrite auth.service.ts from a file on "customer" folder

Tags: angular, customization, symlink, angular-services, directory-structure

I know this may be a noob question, but I'm facing the problem of customizing the login process for a single customer.
I have the service auth.service.ts in the "core" project and I need to replace it from a file on "customer" folder outside the main project.

I have the main auth.service.ts is located in *src/app/core/services* folder structure and the customer version of that file is located in *src/customer/services*.
Please note, the "customer" folder is not really placed under "src" but is a symbolic link to another path.

How can I tell the angular project to load *src/customer/services/auth.service.ts* instead of *src/app/core/services/auth.service.ts*?

Also, if there is a better method to place all customer file/folders instead of making a symbolic link, any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: not sure if it works for your usecase, but it can. there is a fileReplacements option in angular.json which can make you different builds  with different files. by default it is used to choose either environment.ts or environment.prod.ts file

Answer (score 1):

Add an interface to both Services

```
export class AuthService implements IAuthService {}
```

Then provide both services with multiple true flag.

```
[ provide: IAuthService, useClass: fromCore.AuthService, multi: true]
[ provide: IAuthService, useClass: fromCustomer.AuthService, multi: true]
```

That will lead to an provided array where you inject it.

```
@Inject(IAuthService) authServices: IAuthService[]
```

You can use either service at 0 or service at 1 depending on customer found.

```
this.authServices[isSpecialCustomer(customer) ? 1 : 0].login();
```